# Adding background image to qbutton using qss with setting position?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I have added two pictures to my qss and I have one on the pressed event while the other is the button's normal state.

However, it is showing a few images of the picture in one button:

[image]

[image]

How can I make it so that I only have one image and I can move the image to anywhere in the button?

Here is the stylesheet applied:

```
self.button1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-image: url(resources/picture1.png); border-radius: 8px; background-color:lightgrey;} QPushButton:pressed{background-image: url(resources/picture2.png); border-radius: 8px; background-color:red;}")
```

Comment: The first url is absolute, and means that it will try to access a file in the `resources` folder of the root system; the second uses [Qt resources](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html), so it can only work as long as you created a resource file in Designer and compiled it with the related rcc tool; the third is invalid; the fourth only works as long as `resources` is within the *working directory* (the path from which the script is run). This is assuming that the problem is actually the path, so please [edit] the question with the *actual* error, not a generic description of it.

Comment: @musicamante I have changed and edited the question to be much more clear.

Comment: Your previous version of the question (which, by the way, asked about a very different problem) already had a link to the detailed [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-reference.html), including important properties such as `background-repeat` and `background-position`.

Comment: background-repeat does do the trick but is there any other way to set the position perhaps with a larger degree of accuracy eg with px. could margin and padding be used for this? also, I don't understand what background-origin, background-clip and background-attachment do.

Comment: No, at least not without considering the consequences. Remember: QSS (Qt Style Sheets) are only *based* on CSS, and they only use the CSSv2.1 implementation. This means that: 1. you *could* translate the contents using the `padding` property; 2. this will reposition *any content* of the widget (including text); 3. being CSS2.1 (and the QSS code) that old, it doesn't consider modern aspects as HiDPI displays or font scaling. If you just want a "fancy widget" that shows an image at desired position and reacts to mouse events, just create a QWidget subclass and implement its mouse event handlers.

Comment: Note: the documentation you linked already explains the properties you asked about. Please take your time to carefully read the *whole* [Qt Style Sheets documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) and experiment with them, possibly using Qt Designer. Advanced [styling](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html) (either through QSS or QStyle) is not an easy subject, it requires lots of time and patience in reading the documentation, self-aware experience/experiments and, possibly, source code studying ([officially](//code.qt.io/cgit/) or through a [code browser](//codebrowser.dev/)).